# delete multiple folder with prefix using javascript / node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, nodes

I am trying to delete directories so i wrote a code

```
const path= require("path"),
const fs= require("fs");

let dir= path.join(process.cwd(),"tested folders");
if(fs.existsSync(dir)){
 fs.rmSync(dir, { recursive: true, force: true });
}
```

and It is helping me to delete the desire directories
but now I am trying to delete multiple directories as I want to delete all the files who starts with `_testFolder_` as there are multiple files with this prefix

so I made an array and pass the value like this

```
let dir=[path.join(process.cwd(),"tested folders"),path.join(process.cwd(),"_testFolder_*")]

if(fs.existsSync(dir)){
 fs.rmSync(dir, { recursive: true, force: true });
}
```

and trying to delete multiple folder but it not letting me delete even my first folder also how can I delete multiple folder which start with this prefix `_testFolder_` and `tested folder` too

Comment: there are 2 approaches in my mind currently     1) by nodeJS fs    2) by os command using node js,  


which do you want to use?

Comment: which ever approach help me to delete all the mentioned files @bhavesh :)

Answer (score 0):

here is  the code, you can delete all folders

NOTE:- here command is for Linux for another os you can replace it

```
const { exec } = require('child_process');
const path = require("path")
let dir = [path.join(process.cwd(), "tested folders"), path.join(process.cwd(), "_testFolder_*")]
// linux command rm -rf
exec(`rm -rf "${dir.join('" "')}"`);
```

** choosing child process because it reduces code and speed

**using Node js**

```
let fs = require('fs')
// your dir array should be (simple regex)
let regex = [/tested folders/, /_testFolder_/]
let scanDir = process.cwd()
fs.readdirSync(scanDir)
    .filter(f => regex.filter(r => r.test(f)).length)
    .map(f => fs.rmdirSync(scanDir + "/" + f))
```

Comment: and what is another way by using NodeJS
as I am making cli and this cli will run on other OS to so can I get nodejs way ?

Comment: @BhaveshSingh added node js option also